# What's the word for using alternative descriptions in place of a name?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

There's a word for a replacement of a name with a description of that person, place or whatever thing the name belongs to. This is a very common rhetorical device (especially in newspapers and magazines) but I only once saw the name of this device, and I can't recall it.

For example, a journalist writing about Walt Disney might start out by calling him "Disney," but somewhere in the article you might find the journalist replacing the name with with a description, like so: "The media mogul said that he wanted to..."

Anyone know what word I'm talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about *antonomasia*?

> Substituting a descriptive phrase for a proper name, or substituting a
>   proper name for a quality associated with it. (=*periphrasis*)
>
> **Examples**
>
> *You must pray to heaven's guardian for relief.*
>
> *He proved a Judas to the cause.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Silva Rhetoricae:
>   *antonomasia*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/antonomasia.htm)</sub>

Comment: Thank you! That's the word :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the modern form of the age-old *kenning* also known as *Homerian epithet*.

The old poets used such devices for the sake of elegant variation, and also to make mention of the person referred to fit within available metric constraints.