# Is this an example of antonomasia? Or a different literary device?

Tags: names, literary-device

Beowulf often avoids using the names of characters, instead referring to them by some other word, compound word, or phrase. For example, Thomas Meyer's translation mostly refers to Grendel as anything but Grendel:

> "the beast," "Hell's slave," "God's enemy," "deathbringer," "that ghost from another world," "He whose heart feuded with God," "Hellbeast," etc.

Are these examples of antonomasia? Or something else?

Comment: Antonomasia works: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528223/whats-the-word-for-using-alternative-descriptions-in-place-of-a-name/528231#528231

Comment: Is there a noun phrase for 'antonomastic names' themselves? Something like: "Grendel's antonomisms....."